# Xamarin MediaPlugin MediaFile null but image is written to path

Tags: xamarin

I am having a strange issue where by the below code returns null, but if I look in the folder, the image jpg has saved to file

```
    public partial class TaskPage : ContentPage
    {
    private async void TaskPageTaskAnswer_Clicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        MediaFile mediaFile = await CrossMedia.Current.TakePhotoAsync(new StoreCameraMediaOptions { PhotoSize = PhotoSize.MaxWidthHeight, MaxWidthHeight = 1024 });
    }
```

permissions checking is just this at the moment after various attempts

```
public class MainActivity : Xamarin.Forms.Platform.Android.FormsAppCompatActivity
    {
        protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
        {
            TabLayoutResource = Resource.Layout.Tabbar;
            ToolbarResource = Resource.Layout.Toolbar;

            base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);
            CrossCurrentActivity.Current.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Forms.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            FormsMaterial.Init(this, savedInstanceState);
            Xamarin.FormsMaps.Init(this, savedInstanceState);

            LoadApplication(new App());
        }
        public override void OnRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, string[] permissions, [GeneratedEnum] Permission[] grantResults)
        {
            Plugin.Permissions.PermissionsImplementation.Current.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
            Xamarin.Essentials.Platform.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);

            base.OnRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }
```

Also I am having trouble getting the Permissions plugin to return after it has requested permissions. They may be related issues?
I have followed all the steps but there seems to be contrasting info regarding the setup. Some places say to have a MainApplication.cs in the android project, yet the sample for this doesn't have that?

Comment: Could you please share more code of where this is called in your app and where you perform your permission checks. Also, do you only see this issue on Android, or on iOS as well?

Comment: Ive updated the code above to show what im doing to call the plugin, and the permissions setup. It does ask on the device for camera and storage permissions, and it does load the camera and take the picture. If i look in the app permissions section on the device it has them enabled too.

Comment: Sorry yes its just on android

Comment: Sorry,I couldn't reproduce this question,could you please share a  basic demo so that we can test with it?